# Сохранение данных в бесконечном цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пишу програму которая использует бесконечный цикл.Каждый цикл программа должна сохранять 1 переменную для следующего цикла но переменная может меняться с каждым циклом и эти изменения должны как то сохраняться в другую переменную.Я пробовал сделать это через массив но у меня ничего не полусилось из за того что в лист с каждым циклом не сохранял новую переменную а обнавлял старую.

я пробовал решить это через массив но мальнекий опыт не позволил мне этого сделать.Конкретнее я пробовал через лист но лист обновлялся а не записывал новые и старые переменные

Comment: Покажите код, без кода понять  трудно.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

values = []  # Массив со значениями переменной

for i in range(10):
    var = random.randint(1, 100)  # Переменная которую мы сохраняем

    values.append(var)  # Записываем значение var в массив values

print(values)
```

Вывод:

```
[25, 71, 97, 22, 43, 25, 58, 25, 27, 21]
```